How can i make a simple point in makerjs?
What i need in output dxf file
...
POINT
5
30F
8
NOTCH$CCW$L
10
1871.0
20
6.8011667117243633
30
0.0
0
...

I need the simple point information to be in the exported file. How can I do this? I didn't find the solution I needed in the documentation
